# How to use multipart in ionic

Tags: ionic3, multipartform-data, multipart

I am working on ionic 3 application. I have to send image on server. all is working fine but when i upload image it gives me internal server error. I want to send it by using multipart but unfortunately i don't know how to use it in ionic. I am so depressed. Any help would be appreciated. my upload code is as follow.

i have tried this code but unfortunatelly same error

```
saveMultipart(signupentries) {
 let url = this.baseUrl;
 url += "register1";
        const headers = {
          'enctype': 'multipart/form-data;',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'plain/text',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
}; const formData = new FormData();
        const dataJson = {
          'first_name': signupentries.first_name,
          'last_name': signupentries.last_name,
          'email': signupentries.email,
          'phone': signupentries.phone,
          'car_number': signupentries.car_number,
          'license_number': signupentries.license_number,
          'ownership_card': signupentries.ownership_card,
          'expiry_date_license': signupentries.expiry_date_license,
          'driver_picture': signupentries.driver_picture,
          'car_picture': signupentries.car_picture,
        };
        formData.append('dataJson', JSON.stringify(dataJson));
        return this.http.post(url,
            dataJson,
          {headers: headers});
    }
```

```
driverimage($event): void {
    this.file = $event.target.files[0];
    this.signupvm.driver_picture = this.file.name;
  }
```

in view side i am uploading like this as below

```
<ion-item>
        <ion-input
          type="file"
          placeholder="{{ 'driver_picture' | translate }}"
          accept="image/*"
          (change)="driverimage($event)"
        ></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
```

Comment: where do you attach `this.signupvm.driver_picture` to the formdata?

Comment: signUp(signupentries: any) {
    debugger;
    let url = this.baseUrl;
    // url += "register";
    url += "register1";
   
    return this.http
      .post(url, signupentries)
      .map((res: any) => res);


     }

Comment: this one is my service code i dont use formdata

Comment: i simply send the object of model

Comment: i don't know to use form data and its value . i am just new in ionic

Comment: try adding `formData.append('driver_picture', this.file)`

Comment: use like this   driverimage($event): void {
  const formData = new FormData();

    this.file = $event.target.files[0];
    formData.append('driver_picture', this.file) 
    this.signupvm.driver_picture = this.file.name;
  }
 but have same issue

Comment: are you looking to send just the file name or file?

Comment: i want to send just filename

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200546/discussion-between-nidhin-joseph-and-malik-rizwan).

Comment: its saving in dp like 1570428929-.jpg this.